# Matplotlib plot axis reversed for numpy plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
X = np.array([[-1, 1], [-2,-1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
plt.plot(X)
plt.show()
```

If I plot this the first element in each list is Y and the second is X. So for [-1, 1], -1 is Y and 1 is X. Why is this the default and what's the best way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default because (from the help):

> ```
> If *x* and/or *y* is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns
> will be plotted.
> ```

You could do, instead,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.array([[-1, 1], [-2,-1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
plt.plot(X.T[0], X.T[1])
plt.show()
```

which starts at (-1,1) and winds up at (3,2).